# Atom HTML syntax highlight in template literals (for angular2)

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, atom-editor

How can I get HTML syntax highlight in template literals?

Something like this which I've wrote for sublime before:
Here is sublime version https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Sublime-Plugin/pull/189/files
How can I write the same thing for Atom?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was able to achieve this, here is the gist for `ts.cson` file.
form atom typescript plugin on my system:
`/Users/amin/.atom/packages/atom-typescript/grammars/ts.cson`

https://gist.github.com/aminroosta/509476f48f05f4b56db2c0748fedc8fd

This is very useful for angular2 development,
here is an screenshot for atom with `html` and `css` highlights:

[image]

I couldn't find a better regex to match against `template:` and `styles:[`, if anyone can come up with a better regex i will accept their answers.

the important changes in `ts.cson` file are:

```
"template-html":
  name: "meta.template.html.ts"
  begin: "`<!---->"
  beginCaptures:
    "0":
      name: "string.quoted.template.ts"
  end:"`"
  endCaptures:
    "0":
      name: "string.quoted.template.ts"
  patterns: [
    {
      include: "text.html.basic"
    }
  ]
"template-css":
  name: "meta.template.css.ts"
  begin: "`/\\*\\*/"
  beginCaptures:
    "0":
      name: "string.quoted.template.ts"
  end:"`"
  endCaptures:
    "0":
      name: "string.quoted.template.ts"
  patterns: [
    {
      include: "source.css"
    }
  ]
```

### update:

Found a solution:

```
  "template-html":
    name: "meta.template.html.ts"
    begin: "(?<=template\\:)\\s*`"
    beginCaptures:
    "0":
      name: "string.quoted.template.ts"
  end:"`"
  endCaptures:
    "0":
      name: "string.quoted.template.ts"
  patterns: [
    {
      include: "text.html.basic"
    }
  ]
"template-css":
  name: "meta.template.css.ts"
  begin: "(?<=styles\\:)\\s*(\\[)\\s*(`)"
  beginCaptures:
    "2":
      name: "string.quoted.template.ts"
  end:"`"
  endCaptures:
    "0":
      name: "string.quoted.template.ts"
  patterns: [
    {
      include: "source.css"
    }
  ]
```

Here is the updated screenshot:

[image]