# syntax highlighting for HTML in Javascript

Tags: atom-editor

In Atom-editor i am missing syntax highlighting for HTML in es6 Template strings like:

```
`string text`
```

I use atom-dark-syntax and have language javascript installed and up to date but it looks like:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Atom HTML syntax highlight in template literals (for angular2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36700442/atom-html-syntax-highlight-in-template-literals-for-angular2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`language-javascript-plus`](https://atom.io/packages/language-javascript-plus).

You can then do:

```
let template = /*html*/`
    <div>will have syntax highlighting</div>
`;
```

Comment: It seems that css highlighting is not working.

```
var v = /*css*/`
.selector {
  color: red;
}
`
```